# Get Context from Workflow sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

Im designing a workflow in Sharepoint 2010 to run whenever users create itens or update itens... my question is how can i know if the item the fired the workflow was created or updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test if (Created == Modified)

If it is true then it should be created, otherwise it is modified.

That is, as long as you are not doing anything fancy with SystemUpdates or timestamps etc.